# Update sheet with data from userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table and I have the form I built.

1. the user pick a **name** and surname from the table by the combobox in form
2. the user need to choose from combobox "yes/no" about this **name**

I need a vba code (excel) so that it can find the name (after the user picked it) in the table 
and then update the yes/no column by the correct row.

[image: table]

Comment: What is your best shot so far? (show code)

Comment: Table from query/import. Or table that resides fully in Workbook?

Comment: table is from worksheet called "workers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a module and added this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub update_sheet(workername As String)
'--> If the user was selected on the form update column F to Yes
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rowno As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("workers")

    With ws
        rowno = .Range("C:C").Find(workername).Row
        .Cells(rowno, 6).Value = "Yes"
    End With
End Sub
```

On the form code:

```
Private Sub cb_select_change()
    Call update_sheet(cb_select.Value)
End Sub
```

where your combo box is called `cb_select`
[image: Select Doe from the list]

[image: Populates the appropriate cell with Yes]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some work on this to make it into what you need, but it should get you started:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng_ToSearch As Excel.Range
Dim rng_Found As Excel.Range

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Change this to the range that contains your names. I'm assuming that
'it's a single column and has the Yes/No column alongside.
Set rng_ToSearch = Sheet1.Range("MyTable_Names")

'Change the What argument to reflect the name of your form's
'control.
Set rng_Found = rng_ToSearch.Find(What:=Me.ComboBox1.Value, _
    After:=rng_ToSearch.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)


'This shouldn't happen if you've populated the name selection
'box correctly and have not allowed users to add to it.
'This is left as an exercise for the reader.
If rng_Found Is Nothing Then
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 2000, , "Either the selected name was " _
    & "not found in the list, or no selection was made."
End If

'Again, change the control name to your own.
rng_Found.Offset(0, 1) = Me.ComboBox2.Value

ExitPoint:
On Error Resume Next
Set rng_ToSearch = Nothing
Set rng_Found = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

MsgBox "Error in updating users: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description

Resume ExitPoint

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS MY CODE SO FAR

```
Private Sub RefEdit1_BeforeDragOver(Cancel As Boolean, ByVal Data As msforms.DataObject, ByVal x As stdole.OLE_XPOS_CONTAINER, ByVal y As stdole.OLE_YPOS_CONTAINER, ByVal DragState As msforms.fmDragState, Effect As msforms.fmDropEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)

End Sub

Private Sub ClsFrmE_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub





Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("workers")




'???÷? ?? ?????? ?????
If Trim(Me.cmbWN.Value) = "" Then
  Me.cmbWN.SetFocus
  MsgBox "???? ?? ????"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.tbDate.Value) = "" Then
  Me.tbDate.SetFocus
  MsgBox "???? ????? ?????"
  Exit Sub
End If


'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected
With ws
'  .Unprotect Password:="password"
  If Trim(Me.dNdcmb.Value) = "????" Then
  .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = 1
  Else
  .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = 0
  End If
  .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.tbDate.Value
  '.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.cboPart.List(lPart, 1)
'  .Protect Password:="password"
End With

'clear the data
Me.cmbWN.Value = ""
Me.tbDate.Value = ""

Me.cmbWN.SetFocus

ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cFullName As Range
Dim cDnd As Range

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("workers")

For Each cFullName In ws.Range("??????")
  With Me.cmbWN
    .AddItem cFullName.Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cFullName.Offset(0, 1).Value
  End With
Next cFullName

For Each cDnd In ws.Range("??????????")
  With Me.dNdcmb
    .AddItem cDnd.Value

  End With
Next cDnd
Me.dNdcmb.Text = Me.dNdcmb.List(Me.dNdcmb.ListCount - 2)
Me.cmbWN.SetFocus
End Sub
```